# Determine $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$ given $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $S = u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$ is a basis for the subspace V, and
>   that {$v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$} is also a basis for V,
>
> Suppose that $(v_{1})_{S} = (1, 0, -1)$, $(v_{2})_{S} = (2, 5, 1)$,
>   and $(v_{3})_{S} = (0, -4, 3)$, where $(v_{k})_{S}$ is the coordinate vector.
>
> and $v_{1} = (27, 0, 0, 27)$, $v_{2} = (27, -27, 27, 27)$, and $v_{3} =
>  (0, 54, 27, 0)$.
>
> Find $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$.

**My attempt:**

I've found the following:

$v_{1} = (27, 0, 0, 27) = u_{1} - u_{3}$

$v_{2} = (27, -27, 27, 27) = 2u_{1} + 5u_{2} + u_{3}$

$v_{3} = (0, 54, 27, 0) = -4u_{2} + 3u_{3}$

I wish to apply $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$ as the linear combination of $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}$, because I do know of a theorem that $c_{1}(v_{1})_{S} + 
c_{2}(v_{2})_{S} + \cdots + c_{r}(v_{r})_{S} = (c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2} + \cdots + c_{r}v_{r})_{S}$, which would then give me the coordinate vectors of $u$ $\implies$ $u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}$.

I think that's how it should go about, but i'm pretty stuck from the top. Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain the difference between $(v_{k}^{})_{S}$ and $v_{k}^{}$

Comment: @confused $(v_{k})_{S}$ is the _coordinate vector_ of $v$ relative to the basis $S$. For instance, if $v_{1} = c_{1}u_{1} + \cdots + c_{m}u_{m}$, where $c_{1}, \cdots, c_{m}$ are the real numbers, then $(v_{k})_{S}$ is given as $(c_{1}, c_{2}, \cdots, c_{m})$.

Comment: If a subspace and full vector space have same dimensionality, then they should be identical. Then the problem boils down to expressing one set of basis vectors in terms of other basis vectors. Note here both basis vectors you are specifying are written in standard $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Seems that you just have to solve the linear system (invert the matrix with rows = $(v_{k})_{S}$).

Comment: @GCab i might need some elaboration on this

Comment: I added some more details to my answer: is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: So you have $$\begin{bmatrix}
(v_1)_S\\ 
(v_2)_S\\ 
(v_3)_S
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\ 
v_2\\ 
v_3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering the matrices given by each triple of vectors, taken vertically,
**if** I properly understood your question , you have:
$$
\left( {{\bf v}_{\bf 1} |{\bf v}_{\bf 2} |{\bf v}_{\bf 3} } \right)_{5 \times 3}  = \left( {{\bf u}_{\bf 1} |{\bf u}_{\bf 2} |{\bf u}_{\bf 3} } \right)_{5 \times 3} \left( {\matrix{
   1 & 2 & 0  \cr 
   0 & 5 & { - 4}  \cr 
   { - 1} & 1 & 3  \cr 
 } } \right)_{3 \times 3} 
$$

Then to find the ${\bf u}_{\bf k}$'s, given the ${\bf v}_{\bf k}$'s, you simply have to multiply the last, to the right, by the 
inverted matrix.